# no matching service worker detected angular

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I know there are answers to this question and I have tried almost all the answers available on the internet. my goal is to display a popup showing `add to home screen` on mobiles. I know that I am missing a tiny thing that I am not able to figure out. there are 2 things happening

1. service worker gets register successfully when `service-worker.js` is placed inside `src/assets` but the code inside the `service-worker.js` is not executing and I am getting `no matching service worker detected` in `developer console-->application--->manifest`
2. when I place `service-worker.js` inside `src/` it won't even get register and I get an error `Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with the script ('http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js')` in the console.

my current code

service-worker.js
`

```
 console.log('service worker ?')
 self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
     console.log("installed");
 });
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
// Perform some task
  console.log("activated");
});

 self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("fetched");
   event.respondWith(
  fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
    return caches.match(event.request);
  })
  );
});`
```

manifest.json

```
{
"short_name": "DQ",
"name": "DQ Labs",
"theme_color": "#4A90E2",
"background_color": "#F7F8F9",
"display": "standalone",
"icons": [....],
"start_url": "/"
```

}

app.module.ts

`ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })`

app.component.ts

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log("Will the service worker register?");
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('../assets/service-worker.js')
    .then(function(reg){
      console.log("Yes, it did.", reg.scope);
   }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
  });
```

}

Comment: Please note that service works will only works on Https, I believe you are testing it via localhost and opening in mobile browser via same WIFI IP. You need to push your code to https://<<somedomain.com >>to test it out in mobile phone

Comment: yes, I am testing via localhost and as you said I am using the same ipv4 address to access localhost on my mobile. First, I need to get it working on localhost, and then I will test it on the staging server. @Anjum....

Comment: it wont work unless you put it on https

Answer (score 0):

here the tiny mistake I have done is that I didn't change the `start_url` in `manifest.json` pointing to the `service-worker.js` folder. the s`tart_url` should always point to the folder the `service-worker resides. in my case, it is` start_url: '../assets/'`.